# AngularMatTree seems to know there is data, but wont display it

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am attempting to create a super basic POC of the AngularMaterialTree.  It seems to recognize there is data but wont display it.  I'm using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BALaj39rbZE) as my guide, and have a stackblitz [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tree-test-simple?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)  I'm doing my best to strip out as much as possible for this POC to be expanded on later, which is why the hasNestedChildren just returns as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your root nodes have the `prop` field rather than `name`. Because of this, you see no text for root nodes. Make your root nodes consistent with the data your service returns:

```
topLevelData = [
  {
    name: 'people'
  },
  {
    name: 'people again'
  }
]
```

After this, you will your root node content. But, if you expand a root node, you will see no children.

This happens because your data structure is nested. So you need to use the `mat-nested-tree-node` component instead of `mat-tree-node` for nodes with children as illustrated in the [app.component.html](https://github.com/JamiBot/mat-tree-simple/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html#L9) referenced in the mentioned video.

Then, you need to add a placeholder for the node's children. To do this, it's necessary to use the `matTreeNodeOutlet` directive as demonstrated in [line 20](https://github.com/JamiBot/mat-tree-simple/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html#L20) of the same file.

After these two steps, your markup will look like:

```
<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
  <div class="mat-tree-node">
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.name}}
  </div>
  <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
    <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
  </ul>
</mat-nested-tree-node>
```

Don't forget to add the `example-tree-invisible` CSS class to hide collapsed nodes as illustrated in the [app.component.scss](https://github.com/JamiBot/mat-tree-simple/blob/master/src/app/app.component.scss#L2) file:

```
.example-tree-invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

However, the TreeList component will obtain all nodes at once. Since you have no nodes that don't have children in your sample, this will lead to a StackOverflow exception. You **have to limit** the number of nodes in your example. For example, I've added a counter:

```
let counter = 0;

hasNestedChild = (node) => {
  if (counter == 20) {
    return false;
  }
  counter++;
  return true;
}
```

Here is an updated [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tree-test-simple-inpk79?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: This is the first time someone has solved every problem I've had in one swoop and thank you.

Comment: Great to hear that, @MelvinGruschow. To mark this thread as solved, accept my answer as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.